# im new to python , im curently using python 3x but i always get this error , can someone help me

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Dog():
   snip

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "dog", line 1, in <module> class Dog(): snip File "dog", line 1, in Dog class Dog(): snip 
NameError: name 'snip' is not defined
```

Comment: ...Do you ***actually*** get `NameError: name 'snip' is not defined`?

Comment: Wait did you really actually use `snip` in the class definition?

Comment: Why did you put `snip` into your code if it causes an error?

Comment: @melpomene I'd rather we show _new contributors_ how to use the site. Editing their question when there's ambiguity is not helpful in the long run. They need to clarify themselves otherwise we're all guessing here.

Comment: @AndrasDeak What are you talking about?

Comment: You should include what you intend to do in the code. In the current situation we can say that deleting everything "fixes" the error.

Comment: @melpomene I'm talking about [the edit you approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20689060).

Comment: @AndrasDeak You're making it sound like I alone was responsible for the edit. Someone else made the edit and two other people already approved it, so it probably would've gone through anyway. I just fixed a formatting issue.

Comment: Just in case this isn't clear: `snip` is not valid python code; it's a placeholder. I don't know where you copied this code from, but clearly they decided to omit the class body in order to make the code shorter (and they expected you to know what the *real* code in the class body is).

Comment: @melpomene I admit that when I left the comment I thought that you edited that yourself, only to see right after that you only approved the edit of someone else. I didn't clarify because I chastised Aran (the other approver) in chat for the same thing :P I agree this is not as bad as I originally thought, sorry. But still I don't think we should edit ambiguities away in the questions of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the constructor ,

here you should define what is the arguments that you are passing

```
class Dog:
   def __init__(self,name,age):
       self.name = name
       self.age  = age
       # this way you are telling the class what is the argument you are passing
       # and how to assign it as class property


my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name+ ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Comment: thanks its working but what is --snip-- in python 3x?

Comment: I dont know , where did you saw this snipp ? I guessed its like (etc ...) :D